# Using Inheritance to Create a Derived Class in Python

Tags: python, class, object, inheritance

create a derived class from a base class, and then use the derived class in a Python program. The program should create two Motorcycle objects, and then set the Motorcycle’s speed, accelerate the Motorcycle object, and check its sidecar status.
This class must be used to run through the following class:

```
class Motorcycle: 

    maxspeed = 0
    minspeed = 0
    sidecar = ""

    def __init__(self, maxspeed, minspeed, sidecar):
        self.maxspeed = maxspeed
        self.minspeed = minspeed
        self.sidecar = sidecar
    def sidecar(self):
        self.get_sidecar = True
        return self.get_sidecar
    def speed(self, speed):
        self.speed = self.minspeed + self.accelerate
        return self.speed

    def accelerate(self, accelerate):
        self.accelerate = accelerate
        if (self.accelerate + self.minspeed) > self.maxspeed:
            print("This motorcycle cannot go that fast")
```

Following class:

```
from Motorcycle import Motorcycle

motorcycleOne = Motorcycle(90.0, 65.0, True)
motorcycleTwo = Motorcycle(85.0, 60.0, False)

motorcycleOne.accelerate(30.0)
motorcycleTwo.accelerate(20.0)

print("The current speed of motorcycleOne is " + str(motorcycleOne.speed))
print("The current speed of motorcycleTwo is " + str(motorcycleTwo.speed))

if motorcycleOne.sidecar:
   print("This motorcycle has a sidecar")
else:
   print("This motorcycle does not have a sidecar")

if motorcycleTwo.sidecar:
   print("This motorcycle has a sidecar")
else:
   print("This motorcycle does not have a sidecar")
```

I keep receiving this message for retrieving the speed: is bound method......
I am not sure where to go from here if any one could offer any advice I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing attributes and methods.
Your "speed" should be an attribute of your class, while "accelerate" should be a method that modifies that attribute.
Some code to show what I mean.

```
class Motorcycle:

    def __init__(self, maxspeed, minspeed, sidecar):
        self.maxspeed = maxspeed
        self.minspeed = minspeed
        self.speed = minspeed # Initial speed is equal to minspeed
        self.sidecar = sidecar

    # Printing methods
    # Print sidecar status
    def has_sidecar(self):
        if self.sidecar:
            print("This motorcycle has a sidecar")
        else:
            print("This motorcycle does not have a sidecar")
    # Print speed
    def how_fast(self):
        print ("The current speed of this motorcycle is {}".format(self.speed))

    # Methods to change your sidecar status:
    def add_sidecar(self):
        self.sidecar = True
    def remove_sidecar(self):
        self.sidecar = False
    # Method to accelerate
    def accelerate(self, accelerate):
        if (self.speed + accelerate) > self.maxspeed:
            print("This motorcycle cannot go that fast")
        else:
            self.speed += accelerate

motorcycleOne = Motorcycle(90.0, 65.0, True)
motorcycleTwo = Motorcycle(85.0, 60.0, False)

motorcycleOne.accelerate(30.0)
motorcycleTwo.accelerate(20.0)

motorcycleOne.how_fast()
motorcycleTwo.how_fast()

motorcycleOne.has_sidecar()
motorcycleTwo.has_sidecar()
```

Gives:

```
This motorcycle cannot go that fast
The current speed of this motorcycle is 65.0
The current speed of this motorcycle is 80.0
This motorcycle has a sidecar
This motorcycle does not have a sidecar
```

...

But you are not subclassing a class from a base class.

Answer (score 0):

`speed` and `sidecar` are both methods; you need to call them.

```
print("The current speed of motorcycleOne is " + motorcycleOne.speed())
```

Note, you don't seem to have followed the instructions to create a base and derived class.